# Passing an array to signalr hub but it is not hitting the back end c# code

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, signalr

i am trying to Pass an array to signalr hub but it is not hitting the back end c# code

here is my js code

```
    $('input').focusout(function () {

var number_values = [];
var string_values = [];

var count = 0;

$("#regdrugitem input[type='number']").each(function () {
    number_values[count] = { 'name': $(this).attr('id'), 'val': 
$(this).val(), 'required': $(this).attr('required') };
    count++;
});
 var   count1 = 0;
$("#regdrugitem input[type='text']").each(function () {
    string_values[count1] = { 'name': $(this).attr('id'), 'val': 
$(this).val(), 'required': $(this).attr('required') };
    count1++;
});
  $.connection.regitem_hub.server.regitem(number_values, string_values);
  });
```

And c# code is

```
  public void regitem(iteminfo[] number_values, iteminfo[] string_values)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate ()
        {
            JsonResult msg = ric.insert_Item(number_values);
            Clients.Caller.recieve_data(msg);
        }));

    }
```

Comment: Where do you start the connection?

Comment: At document. ready function in my other file

Comment: show all of your code which contains signlar stuff

Comment: Where is you HUB class?

Comment: The menthod from hub class that i am calling is given above